# how to access a view from a JDBC database on on-prem oracle server by aws glue job?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, aws-glue

I need to extract a view from an on-prem oracle database by using AWS Glue. I can successfully point the crawler to read from database tables. But if I try to point it to a database view, nothing happens. Unfortunately, all our data is abstracted behind views. Should this work?

And also when extracting a table or view from a JDBC database, does it always have to create a table in AWS Glue Data Catalogue first?

Comment: Accessing views should work exactly the same as accessing tables, if your Glue job can read from the tables but not the views this is almost certainly a permissions issue related to the Oracle user in your JDBC connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*But if I try to point it to a database view, nothing happens. Unfortunately, all our data is abstracted behind views. Should this work?*

> > Unfortunately Glue crawler does not support crawling views.

*And also when extracting a table or view from a JDBC database, does it always have to create a table in AWS Glue Data Catalogue first?*

> > Yes and no

If you want to only use Glue native DynamicFrame then the table metadata has to be crawled first and stored in Glue catalog.

If you are not worried about DynamicFrames then you can leverage spark JDBC where you can read tables and views inside your Glue job.For this you don't need metadata to be present in Glue catalog. Refer to [this](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/sql-databases.html) and [this](https://www.progress.com/tutorials/jdbc/accessing-data-using-jdbc-on-aws-glue) to know more about reading data via JDBC into spark DataFrame.

Comment: where is the source info ?